# Integration test for spring jdbc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

Let's say we have a service layer :

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    @Autowired
    private MyDAO myDAO;

    @Transactional
    public void myMethod(SomeObject someObject) {
       myDAO.insertIntoMyDb(someObject);

    }
}
```

Let us say myDAO uses spring jdbc :

```
@Repository
public class MyDAOImpl implements MyDAO {

    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public void insertIntoMyDb(SomeObject object) {

        // some code before this where we get query and param

        int numberOfRowsUpdated = jdbcTemplate.update(query,param);

        if(numberOfRowsUpdated != 1)
            throw new Exception("Error while inserting a record in database. Actual records inserted : " + numberOfRowsUpdated);
    }


}
```

I want to write 2 tests.

The first test will check my dao layer only. I want to make a jdbc call here , get data and verify. I don't want to mock them.

The second test is integration test. I want my service layer to call Dao layer. Note that there is transaction. Now this will give me data from DAO. Again DAO has to connect to db to get data.

I am using spring boot. My database properties are present in applicationITest.properties file.

How to do these 2 testing ? What is the correct annotations I have to use ? Can some one provide an example ?

Comment: Need some clarification: a) Are you testing the transactional behavior of the service layer or the DAO layer? b) Do you want to test the JDBC code?

Comment: Both. I want 2 tests. one which checks (service+dao) and other that checks dao. I dont want to check standalone service layer by mocks. Things get complicated as we also have transaction in service layer

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin What you're asking is covered by the SPring documentation. Read it, and try something. There is no much point in testing the service layer without mocking the DAO layer: the tests will be slower, harder to write, harder to maintain, and your service doesn't do anything anyway other than delegating to the DAO. If you want to test that Spring transactions work fine, that's not really helpful: Spring has already tested that.

Comment: @JBNizet the above code is just a sample. Service layer has a lot of business logic and calls more than one Dao. Also, I read spring documentation but not very clear. Hence, the question.

Comment: Try something, and experiment before asking questions. Then if stuck, come back here with what you've tried, and with the precise problem you're having. Beware: you might learn things by doing this.

Comment: How do you know i have not tried ?  Please don't spam comments as your comments are not really to answer I am seeking.

Comment: If you have tried something, then post what you have tried, and tell us which issue you're facing with what you have tried. That's how it works here.

Answer (score 2):

a) Rollback will happen by default as long as you annotate your Test class with `@Transactional`. Documentation about [Test-managed transactions](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-tx-test-managed-transactions).

sample test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyTestConfig.class)
@Transactional
public class MyClassTest {
   //..

   @Test
   public void myTest() {
      //..
   }

   //..
}
```

b) Yes you can enforce the commit using the [@Commit](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/Commit.html) (added in Spring 4.2) test annotation. [Here's the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#commit).